# Probability Density Function vs. Probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, terminology, normal-distribution

What is the difference between a probability and a probability density function?

$\bullet$ Is it true that "in a probability density function, the area under the curve tells you the probability"?
So consider a Gaussian probability density function, $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}$, now what is the *probability* of $x$ be equal to $\mu$? The area under a point in a curve is zero, isn't it?

$\bullet$ What does it mean when one says "the normal distribution is a probability distribution", so the total area under the normal curve is 1? Do we have "distributions" that are not a probability distribution?

Reference: [Normal Distribution | Examples, Formulas, & Uses - Scribbr](https://www.scribbr.com/statistics/normal-distribution/#:%7E:text=In%25)

I'm trying to understand this paper[[Oded Regev](https://cims.nyu.edu/%7Eregev/). "[On lattices, learning with errors, random linear codes, and cryptography](https://cims.nyu.edu/%7Eregev/papers/qcrypto.pdf)", in Journal of ACM, 2009. *Section 2. Preliminaries, pages 12-15*].

Comment: What does it mean when one says "the normal distribution is a probability distribution", so the total area under the normal curve is 1? ...Who says this, as I have never heard this before.

Comment: @AndrewZhang In the reference: [Normal Distribution | Examples, Formulas, & Uses - Scribbr](https://www.scribbr.com/statistics/normal-distribution/#:%7E:text=In%25).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Everything you say is correct. Probability measure would be a more technically correct term. There are general measures which don’t sum up to 1 - you normally normalize them, dividing by the total, so it does sum to 1. If the integral is infinite, you can’t define a probability (e.g. the Lebesgue measure has density 1 on all real numbers, but since it’s total is infinite, it’s impossible to describe a uniformly chosen random real number and trying to use one leads to paradoxes).

There is a complicated more general notion of distribution but it doesn’t really generalize probability and is more useful in advanced analysis.